# How to add panel with event button in wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to ask is it possible to add wx.Panel with event button in wxpython? There are plenty examples how to switch panels Hide first one and show second, but they are useless for me. I want to create panel with add button. For example I have panel something like this

```
import wx
import wx.grid as grid

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent = parent)


class SecondPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent,a,b):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        MyGrid=grid.Grid(self)
        MyGrid.CreateGrid(a, b)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(MyGrid, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="test",
                          size=(800,600))
        self.splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self)

        self.panelOne = MainPanel(self.splitter)


        self.panelTwo = SecondPanel(self.splitter, 1, 1)
        txtOne = wx.StaticText(self.panelOne, -1, label = "piradoba", pos = (20,10))
        self.txtTwo = wx.StaticText(self.panelOne, -1, label = "", pos = (40,80))
        self.txtPlace = wx.TextCtrl(self.panelOne, pos = (20,30))
        button = wx.Button(self.panelOne, label = "search", pos = (40,100))
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Onbutton)
        self.splitter.SplitHorizontally(self.panelOne, self.panelTwo)
        self.splitter.SetMinimumPaneSize(20)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.splitter, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
   def Onbutton(self, event):
        var=self.txtPlace.GetValue()
        if len(var) == 9 or len(var) == 11:
           ???????????????????????????????????????????????

if __name__ == "__main__":
app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainFrame()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

for example now I want to add new panel with this event what can I do? and I want to create this panel with event.

Comment: Your informations are useless for us (so others downvotes you). What did you try to do ? Show some code.

Comment: I edited so now you can see

Comment: Where do you want to add new panel - in another panel, another splitter, etc. ? Do you have place for new panel ? Maybe try to add new panel in traditional way - in `__init__` and then you can try to move that code to `onbutton`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it is what you need but in this example you have:

- panel with button and event
- button call function in mainframe
- mainframe add next panel (with grid) to boxsizer

Tested on Linux Mint + Python 2.7.4

```
import wx
import wx.grid as grid

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent = parent)

        self.txtOne = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label = "piradoba", pos = (20,10))
        self.txtPlace = wx.TextCtrl(self, pos = (20,30))
        self.txtTwo = wx.StaticText(self, -1, label = "", pos = (20,40))

        button = wx.Button(self, label = "search", pos = (20,70))
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)

    def onButton(self, event):
        var=self.txtPlace.GetValue()
        if len(var) == 9 or len(var) == 11:
            print "???"
        # MainPanel->SplitterWindow->MainFrame ( 2x GetParent() )
        self.GetParent().GetParent().AddPanel()

class SecondPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent,a,b):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        MyGrid=grid.Grid(self)
        MyGrid.CreateGrid(a, b)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(MyGrid, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="test", size=(800,600))

        self.splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self)

        self.panelOne = MainPanel(self.splitter)
        self.panelTwo = SecondPanel(self.splitter, 1, 1)

        self.splitter.SplitHorizontally(self.panelOne, self.panelTwo)
        self.splitter.SetMinimumPaneSize(20)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.splitter, 2, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

    def AddPanel(self):
        self.newPanel = SecondPanel(self, 1, 1)
        self.sizer.Add(self.newPanel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Layout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I like your example. I also solved that problem yesterday, it was easier than i expected. But anyway I'll accept your answer.